# Setting an exact percentage of patches red and green color

Tags: netlogo

In setup, I am trying to set an exact percentage of the overall patches red pcolor or green pcolor.
I am using the standard patch environment, with 1089 total patches.
I have two sliders:

- slider1 (for setting up to 250 green turtles)
- slider 2 (for setting up to 250 red turtles)

Is there a way to set an exact percentage of the 1089 total patches red and the remaining percentage green?
Adapting code from a helpful Q&A previously posted on this site, I have this draft coding:

```
to color-patches

  let total slider1 + slider2
  let p-red   slider1 / total
  let p-green slider2 / total

  ask patches [
    let x random-float 1.0
    if x <= p-red [set pcolor red]
    if x <= p-green [set pcolor green]
  ]
end
```

Any helpful advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`n-of`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-of)!

```
ask n-of (p-red * count patches) patches [ set pcolor red ]
ask patches with [ pcolor != red ] [ set pcolor green ]
```

Comment: Wow, Bryan.  That's a really incisive and quick response.  I appreciate your help.  I will try your solution tomorrow.  Naturally, I would not have posted a question unless I was stymied.  Thanks again, Crane.